# Leer contenido fichero Json en Java

Tags: java, json, java-8

estoy aprendiendo a programar en el lenguaje Java, y me preguntaba como podía obtener los datos de un fichero JSON. Tengo el paquete json, que lo he obtenido de Maven repository y para compilar el programa utilizo un "java -cp paquete_jason programa.java".

No tengo problemas a la hora de compilar, únicamente me gustaría que me aclareis como podría obtener datos de un fichero JSON con la siguiente estructura:

```
 [ 
  {
   "login": "nombre_usuario",
   "id": 1234 
 } 
]
```

He encontrado el siguiente código en internet, pero no sabría adaptarlo a mis necesidades, ¿me podríais hechar un cable?:

```
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths; 
import org.json.JSONArray;  
import org.json.JSONObject; 

public class JSONRead4 {public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
     String line = null;
     try {
        line = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file3JSON")));
     }        
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
       ex.printStackTrace();
     }
     JSONArray recs = new JSONArray(line);
     for(Object rec : recs) {
        JSONObject aula = ((JSONObject) rec).getJSONObject("Aula");
        String idAula = aula.getString("id");
        if(idAula.equals("128")){
          System.out.println("  --- ");
          System.out.println(idAula + " (seleccionada) ");
          JSONArray ar = aula.getJSONArray("alums");
          for(Object obj : ar) {
            System.out.println(" " + ((JSONObject) obj).getString("nombre"));
          }
           System.out.println("  --- ");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println(idAula + " (no seleccionada) ");
        }
     }    
   }  
}
```

Es decir, que tendría que modificar para que pudiese mostrarme por pantalla todos los datos del fichero json, ya sea el campo LOGIN e ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifico un poco tu código y en el "fichero" añado una entrada mas. El resto está en los comentarios.

```
    // asumismos que esto es el contenido del fichero ya leído
    String line = 
            "["
            + "     { \"login\": \"nombre usuario\", \"id\": 1234 }, "
            + "     { \"login\": \"nombre otro usuario\", \"id\": 5678 } "
            + "]";

    // esto crea un JSONArray
    JSONArray recs = new JSONArray(line);

    // el JSONArray se compone de JSONObjects 
    // (pero esto el compilador no lo sabe, asi que para iterar usamo Object)
    for (Object rec : recs) {// iteramos sobre los objetos

        // hacemos el casta a JSONObject, así el compilador se siente contento
        JSONObject obj = ((JSONObject) rec);

        // de cada JSONObject sacamos los datos que nos interesan
        int id = obj.getInt("id");// esto debe ser int, no string por el tipo de dato en el fichero
        String login = obj.getString("login");

        // mostrar
        System.out.println(id + " : " + login);
    }
```

Si tienes problemas con algo, simplemente pregunta.

Saludos

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta, y sobretodo, gracias por dejar esos comentarios que explican que hace cada paso. Me ayuda muchísimo a comprender como funciona. ¡Mil gracias amigo!